# How to disable the validation message in ionic 3 radio button even though when nothing is selected while at the form is loaded for the first time?

Tags: android, mobile, ionic3, angular6, hybrid

I am using the ionic radio buttons to choose between the genders in my form. Currently the validation message is showing in gender formcontrol if nothing is selected. But even if nothing is selected i don't want to show the validation message while the form is loaded. But if we click the submit button without choosing any one of the gender radio buttons,it should show the validation message at that time. How can I achieve it?

Here's my HTML for radio buttons:

```
 <ion-row radio-group [(ngModel)]="vm.gender" class="gender" formControlName = "genderradiobtn" >
                              <ion-col>
                               <ion-item>

                                  <ion-label color="textcolor">Gender</ion-label>
                              </ion-item>
                               </ion-col>
                              <ion-col>
                             <ion-item>
                             <ion-label color="textcolor">Male</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="Male"></ion-radio>
                               </ion-item>
                                </ion-col>
                                <ion-col>
                                   <ion-item>
                              <ion-label color="textcolor">Female</ion-label>
                            <ion-radio value="Female"></ion-radio>
                           </ion-item>
                              </ion-col>
                               </ion-row>
                               <div class="error-message-emp" *ngIf="formemp.controls.genderradiobtn.errors && (formemp.controls.genderradiobtn.touched||formemp.controls.genderradiobtn.invalid)">
                                  <span *ngIf="formemp.controls.genderradiobtn.errors?.required">Gender is required</span>
                                </div>
```

in my ts:

```
initializeValidators(){
genderradiobtn: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
}
```

Comment: can you share full code for your formGroup? including ts file please.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko thanks friend, the issue has been solved now